What is the most efficient way to sort a large dataset in Python?
I have a large dataset (millions of entries) that needs to be sorted. What are the best practices or most efficient methods for sorting such a dataset in Python? Specifically:
Is Python's built-in sorted() or list.sort() sufficient for large datasets?
What are the memory implications of sorting a large dataset in memory?
Are there external libraries or algorithms better suited for this task if the dataset cannot fit into memory?
I initially tried using Python’s built-in sorted() function to sort my dataset, which is a list containing millions of integers. While it worked for smaller datasets during testing, I noticed significant slowdowns and high memory usage when scaling up to the full dataset.
I was expecting sorted() to handle large datasets efficiently since it uses Timsort, but I suspect the issue might be related to memory limitations or the way I’m implementing the sorting. I’m also unsure if there are better approaches for handling datasets that are too large to fit in memory, which is why I’m looking for advice on best practices or alternative methods (e.g., distributed systems or external sorting).

"a list containing millions of integers" This is an inefficient container in the first place (both for the memory usage and performance). You should try Numpy. Numpy arrays are much more compact in memory and they support fast sorting using very efficient algorithms (eg. radix sort and SIMD-aware bitonic sort). No need for distributed sorting : this tends not to scale on one node already (thing only get worse with more nodes).


approaches for handling datasets that are too large to fit in memory

If you encountered problem with running out of RAM, but you have more memory available on your hard disk, then consider using sorted-in-disk.
